# Removing redunant Gene Ontology Terms using sematic similarity

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with redundant Gene Ontology (GO) Terms. I want to use sematic similarity to remove these redundant Terms. Do you guys know any packages on python I could use to do this? thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you could do it with a well-written function and a lambda.  Why do you need a package?  Who knows your problem better than you do?

Comment: There are a number of NLP packages that you might look into. `spaCy` and `pytorch` might be starting points. Both support calculating similarities.